# Find consecutive sub-vectors of length k out of a numeric vector which satisfy a given condition

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector in R, say

```
v= c(2,3,5,6,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4)
```

Now, I have to find all the consecutive sub-vector of size 4 out of it with the condition that each element of the sub-vector must be greater than 2 and all sub-vector must be disjoint in the sense that non of the two sub-vector can contain same index element. So my output will be:

```
(3,5,6,7),(3,4,5,7),(5,6,7,11)
```

**Edited:** 
Other examples for illustration purpose: for,

```
v=c(3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

output will be :

```
(3,3,3,3), (3,3,3,3),(3,3,3,3).
```

and for,

```
v= c(2,3,5,5,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4)
```

output will be

```
(3,5,5,7),(3,4,5,7),(5,6,7,11)
```

The second condition on the output simply says that if we found any sub- array say `(v[m],v[m+1],v[m+2],v[m+3])` with each element greater than > 2 then it will goes into my output and the next sub-array can only be start from `v[m+4]`(if possible)

Comment: did you already try to write a R function for this? What did you get, and what happened?

Comment: @user3559153 I just updated the code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses `embed()` to create a matrix of lags and then extracts the desired rows from this matrix:

```
v <- c(2,3,5,6,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4)

e <- embed(v, 4)
ret <- which(
  apply(e, 1, function(x)all(x > 2)) &
  apply(e, 1, function(x)length(unique(x)) == 4)
)
rows <- ret[c(1, 1 + which(diff(ret) > 4))]

e[rows, 4:1]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    5    6    7
[2,]    3    4    5    7
[3,]    5    6    7   11
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get the uniqueness condition in ret. I think there is some confusion here for 2nd condition. The second condition simply says that if we found any sub- array say (v[m],v[m+1],v[m+2],v[m+3]) with each element greater than > 2 then it will goes into my output and the next subarray can only be start from v[m+4](if possible). e.g for v=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3) Output:(3,3,3,3), (3,3,3,3),(3,3,3,3). for v= c(2,3,5,5,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4) it will be (3,5,5,7),(3,4,5,7),(5,6,7,11).[Above code give "none"  and  (5,7,6,3),(3,4,5,7),(5,6,7,11) resp.]

Comment: As far as I can tell, my code works with your sample data.  If your sample data is insufficient, then I suggest you modify your question with more information.  It is too difficult to understand what you want from this comment.

Comment: +1 for showing me another function (embed) that I'd missed seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  fun1 <- function(vec, n, cond1) {
  lst1 <- lapply(1:(length(vec) - n+1), function(i) {
    x1 <- vec[i:(i + (n-1))]
    if (all(diff(x1) >= 0) & all(x1 > cond1)) 
        x1
   })
   indx <- which(sapply(lst1, length) == n)
  indx2 <- unlist(lapply(split(indx, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(indx) != 1))), function(x) x[seq(1, 
    length(x), by = n-1)]))
   lst1[indx2]
}


v1 <- c(3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
v2 <- c(2,3,5,5,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4)
v3 <- c(2,3,5,6,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4)

fun1(v1,4,2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 3 3 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 3 3 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 3 3 3

 fun1(v2,4,2)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 3 5 5 7

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5 7

#[[3]]
#[1]  5  6  7 11

fun1(v3,4,2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 5 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5 7

#[[3]]
#[1]  5  6  7 11
```

Comment: There are two conditions: 1. All elements of the sub-arrays should be grater than 2.                                                              2. The second condition simply implies that if we found any sub-vector (v[m],v[m+1],v[m+2],v[m+3]) of size 4 where each element>2, then it will the part of the output and the next desired sub-vector will be start with element v[m+4] (if the next 3 elements from it satisfied the condition1). Its clear now?

Comment: @user3559153  I was confused by the `consecutive number`.  There is a gap between `3 and 5` in the first case, so also in other cases.  Anyway, for the example provided, I got the result as you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea based on `rle`:

```
ff = function(x, size, thres)
{
   valid_subsets = sapply(head(seq_along(x), -(size - 1)), 
                          function(i) all(x[i:(i + (size - 1))] > thres))
   r = rle(valid_subsets)

   lapply(unlist(mapply(function(a, b) a + (seq_len(b) - 1) * size, 
                        (cumsum(r$lengths) - r$lengths + 1)[which(r$values)], 
                        (r$lengths[which(r$values)] + size - 1) %/% size)), 
          function(i) x[i:(i + (size - 1))])
}

ff(c(3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 4, 2)
ff(c(2,3,5,6,7,6,3,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,1,1,2,5,6,7,11,2,3,4), 4, 2)
```

Testing on another vector (I assume this is the correct output):

```
set.seed(4); xx = sample(1:10, 20, T)
xx
# [1]  6  1  3  3  9  3  8 10 10  1  8  3  2 10  5  5 10  6 10  8
ff(xx, 4, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 3 9 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 10  5  5 10
```

Unless I'm missing something, on "xx" (as well as on other cases) the other posted answers do not seem to work:

```
fun1(xx, 4, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1]  3  8 10 10

#e[rows, 4:1]
#[1]  9  3  8 10
```